# When to use double quotes/single quotes in parentheses?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

When to use and not use single or double quotes within functions?

for example:

```
function convertToInteger(str) {
  return parseInt(str); // why do we not use double-quotes here? is this as simple as we never use quotes around arguments when calling a function?
}

convertToInteger("56");
```

Comment: `str` is a [variable](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/Variable), `"str"` is a [string literal](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Glossary/String). By the way, please use `parseInt` [_with_ the second parameter, `10`](/q/16880327/4642212). Consider using [`Number`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#Function_syntax) or [`parseFloat`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.

Comment: read this perhaps to learn about functions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable value should be in quotes , variable name should not be in quotes .

convertToInteger("56");

or

var datavalue="56";

convertToInteger(datavalue);

Comment: "*Variable value should be in quotes*" only if it's a string;

Answer (score 1):

the variables inside the function are called arguments. They serve to store the item you passed.
As you passed it, it will use whatever value you enter, but if you put a value in quotes, you would be setting a fixed value.

Comment: "*the variables inside the function are called arguments.*"  they are called *parameters* and only when part of the function definition. There can be non-parameter variables in the body. Argument is what is *passed in* to a function. So `function fn(a, b) {}` defines parameters, `fn(1, 2)` passes arguments.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, but thanks for understanding.